# Double pointer with array in another function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

I have to create a program that has an array of costumers (structs that contain name, code and documentation) and functions to insert, remove and list all of them in order of code. I'm not understanding what I should do. Please note that the parameters for `insertCostumer`, `removeCostumer` and `listCostumer` cannot be changed.

Piece of code 01:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAX_REG 10

typedef struct _costumer {
    int code;
    char name[50];
    char documentation[20];
} costumer;
```

Piece of code 02:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    costumer *costumers[MAX_REG];
    costumer **p_costumer;
    p_costumer = &costumers[0];
    int count = 0;

    memset(costumers, 0, sizeof(costumers));

    //Some code to check what to do using a switch
            case '1': insertCostumer(p_costumer, &count); getch(); break;
            case '2': removeCostumer(p_costumer, &count); getch(); break;
            case '3': listCostumers(p_costumer, &count); getch(); break;
    //Some code
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Piece of code 03:

```
void insertCostumer(costumer **p_costumer, int *count){
    char aux[50];
    char aux2[20];

    if(*count < MAX_REG) {
      *p_costumer = (costumer *) malloc(sizeof(costumer));
      printf("\nInsert the code: ");
      gets(aux);
      (*p_costumer)->code = atoi(aux);

      printf("Insert the name: ");
      gets(aux);
      strcpy((*p_costumer)->name, aux);

      printf("Insert the documentation: ");
      gets(aux2);
      strcpy((*p_costumer)->documentation, aux2);

      (*count)++;
      p_costumer = &*p_costumer[*count];

    } else {
        printf("List full! Remove a costumer first!\n");
    }
}

void removeCostumer(costumer **p_costumer, int *count){
    char aux3[50];
    int cod;

    printf("\nInsert the code of the costumer to be removed: ");
    gets(aux3);
    cod = atoi(aux3);

    for(int i = 0; i < *count; i++) {
        if(p_costumer[i]->code == cod) {
            strcpy(p_costumer[i]->name, NULL);
            p_costumer[i]->code = 0;
            strcpy(p_costumer[i]->documentation, NULL);
        }
      }
}

void listCostumers(costumer **p_costumer, int *count){
    for(int i = 0; i < *count; i++) {
        printf("Code: %d | Name: %s | Documentation: %s\n", p_costumer[i]->code, p_costumer[i]->name, p_costumer[i]->documentation);
    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong; nothing is working, honestly. I was trying to first insert, list and remove to try and make the sorting part later, but I can't even get this part done. When I list, only the last costumer added is listed, for example.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can't change the arguments to the [various] functions? If this is a school assignment, your instructor is teaching you how to code _badly_. These functions should take a pointer to a [new] "list" struct that has _both_ the base array pointer _and_ the count (e.g.) `struct list { costumer *base; int count; };` This simplifies the design and improves reliability. _Forcing_ you to use double level pointers is just poor practice.

Comment: I think he wants us to use it this way so we can understand how it works or something. Is there a way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I had to refactor a considerable amount of your code, so I don't have a blow by blow description of the changes.

You'll just have to study it a bit.

Note that even if you're passed a double pointer as an argument, doesn't mean you *have* to use it as a double in the body of the functions. Note, in particular, what I did for the count (e.g. `int count = *p_count;` and `*p_count = count;`)

But, it should be noted that the *list* is one of *pointers* to structs and *not* merely a pointer to an array of structs (i.e. there *is* an extra level of indirection). This makes things a bit faster.

Note that, bug fixes aside, the key is the "slide" operation in the remove function.

Because we're "sliding" pointers, this is faster/more efficient with the pointer array. Study this [concept] well.

*Never* use `gets`--always use `fgets`

I've deliberately left off comments. This will allow you to add them as you analyze the code. I've found that this can be a powerful technique for understanding a [foreign] code base.

Anyway, here's the code. I've done some rudimentary testing and it seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include <conio.h>

#define MAX_REG 10
char aux[1000];

typedef struct _costumer {
    int code;
    char name[50];
    char documentation[20];
} costumer;

void
lineget(char *buf,size_t buflen)
{
    char *cp;

    cp = fgets(buf,buflen,stdin);

    if (cp != NULL) {
        cp = strrchr(buf,'\n');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = 0;
    }
}

void
insertCostumer(costumer **p_costumer, int *p_count)
{
    costumer *add;
    int count = *p_count;

    char aux2[20];

    if (count < MAX_REG) {
        add = malloc(sizeof(costumer));

        printf("\nInsert the code: ");
        lineget(aux,sizeof(aux));
        add->code = atoi(aux);

        printf("Insert the name: ");
        lineget(add->name,sizeof(add->name));

        printf("Insert the documentation: ");
        lineget(add->documentation,sizeof(add->documentation));

        p_costumer[count] = add;
        ++count;
    }
    else {
        printf("List full! Remove a costumer first!\n");
    }

    *p_count = count;
}

void
removeCostumer(costumer **p_costumer, int *p_count)
{
    int count = *p_count;
    int cod;
    int i;
    costumer *cur;

    printf("\nInsert the code of the costumer to be removed: ");
    fgets(aux,sizeof(aux),stdin);
    cod = atoi(aux);

    int slide = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cur = p_costumer[i];
        if (cur->code == cod) {
            slide = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (slide) {
        free(cur);
        --count;

        for (;  i < count;  ++i)
            p_costumer[i] = p_costumer[i + 1];

        p_costumer[count] = NULL;
    }

    *p_count = count;
}

void
listCostumers(costumer **p_costumer, int *p_count)
{
    costumer *cur;
    int count = *p_count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i, ++cur) {
        cur = p_costumer[i];
        printf("Code: %d | Name: %s | Documentation: %s\n",
            cur->code, cur->name, cur->documentation);
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    costumer *costumers[MAX_REG];
    costumer **p_costumer;
    char buf[100];

    p_costumer = &costumers[0];
    int count = 0;

    memset(costumers, 0, sizeof(costumers));
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);

    //Some code to check what to do using a switch
    while (1) {
        printf("operation to perform (1=insert, 2=remove, 3=print): ");
        char *cp = fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        switch (cp[0]) {
        case '1':
            insertCostumer(p_costumer, &count);
            break;

        case '2':
            removeCostumer(p_costumer, &count);
            break;

        case '3':
            listCostumers(p_costumer, &count);
            break;
        }
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```